# How to add new organization using nodejs SDK for hyperledger fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am newbie to Hyperledger Fabric.

I need to understand how to add new organization to the hyperledger fabric network using nodejs sdk.

TIA.

Regards,
Heero Punjabi

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new organization to an existing Hyperledger Fabric network is not an easy task for a newbie (not for anybody).

Here is a good example: https://medium.com/@kctheservant/add-a-new-organization-on-existing-hyperledger-fabric-network-2c9e303955b2.

The process is based on `configtxlator` tool (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/configtxlator.html), not in the Node SDK, but you can replace `peer channel` commands with Node SDK routines if you want (https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Channel.html).

Probably you use CAs instead of `cryptogen`, which makes the process a little bit more tiresome.

Comment: thanks for replying. could you pls share NodeJS example. I am able to achieve adding new org using configtxlator.